# List adapter unchecking my toggle button when I scroll. Tried multiple solutions from here but no luck

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewholder, android-togglebutton

my adapter (the style of which has been working for the rest of my app) is now giving me issues. This is the first list that has a toggle-able button. Each listItem has a toggleButton, which when I toggle, scroll down and then back up, it becomes unchecked automatically. I have spent the last 2 days trying unsuccessfully different solutions from SO, from disabling recycling to adding a view holder, neither of which worked.

I know the code may seem like a bit of a mess, but hopefully it is still understandable. The variables have been changed, and I'm pretty sure I got every instance, but I mainly need help with the logic/syntax. I am not showing some of the ViewHolder code that I have, mainly because that would just make it even more confusing.

The String[]s that I have send in an equal amount of string values in each.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

Activity activity;

/**
 * String[] of sender Data
 */

String[] Id, Name, Alert, Instructions, RedText, dawcb; //Alert, Name, and a toggleButton are to be displayed in list

TextView status, date, prescription;

ImageView AlertIcon;

ToggleButton tb;

/**
 * Index of Selected Item
 */
private int _index = -1;

/**
 * Inflate Layout in Application Context
 */
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MultiRenewAdapter(Activity a, String[] Id, String[] Name, String[] Alert, String[] Instructions, String[] RedText, String[] dawcb)
{
    activity = a;
    this.Id = Id;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Alert = Alert;
    this.Instructions = Instructions;
    this.RedText = RedText;
    this.dawcb = dawcb;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


//some code to help save selected items

static class ViewHolder {
protected ImageView alertIcon;
    protected TextView text;
    protected ToggleButton tb;
}

public int getCount()
{
    return Name.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

//    I thought I could try turning off recycling (this is from another post here):
//    @Override
//    public int getViewTypeCount() {
//        //Count=Size of ArrayList.
//        return Name.length;
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
//
//        return position;
//    }



/**
 * Override Get View for custom format
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View vi = convertView;//vi and convertView are null

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    positionInt = position;

//doesn't work since viewHolder is null, and is causing a null pointer exception
    //viewHolder.tb = (ToggleButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    //viewHolder.prescription = (TextView)    //vi.findViewById(R.id.prescription);
    //viewHolder.AlertIcon = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.AlertIcon);


    if (position == _index)
    {
vi.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.DeepSkyBlue));
    }
    else
    {
            vi.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
        if (position % 2 == 0)
        {
            vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
        else
        {
            vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }
    }

    if(convertView==null)
    {

        if (position % 2 == 0)
        {
            vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
        else
        {
            vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }
    }

    tb = (ToggleButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    prescription = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.prescription);
    AlertIcon = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.AlertIcon);

    if(Alert[position].equals("4")){
        AlertIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checktemp);
    }else if(Alert[position].equals("3")){
        AlertIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orange_diamond_temp);
    }else if(Alert[position].equals("2")){
        AlertIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.exclamation_red_temp);
    }else if(Alert[position].equals("1")){
        AlertIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_x_temp);
    } else {
        AlertIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    prescription.setText(Name[position]);

    return vi;
}
public void setClicked(int index)
{
    _index = index;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

I look forward to any and all help.

Thank you!

Comment: Basically getView() will display the GUI and its state, and you're responsible for setting all the GUI elements, including for object tb (ToggleButton). For example, tb.setChecked(true) is valid for that UI. It is up to your code to maintain its state. Unfortunately, I see several problems with your code. I may post a good tutorial for you, if you're still working on this.

Comment: I figured it out. I actually have another issue that I will post a question about. Just took a ton of tries and headaches haha. Thank you for your response though!

Comment: KittyKat, that's great! If you think my comment is helpful, click on the up arrow besides my comment, or anyone else's.

Comment: I would but I am too low of a rank I believe - I don't see any arrow. Sorry!